# Swift iAP Error (Objective-C method * conflicts with optional requirement method)

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

I am following this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1gQklbrgjc

I followed his tutorial to the letter however, when I do this function:

```
 func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    print("removed")
}
```

I get the Full error:

> Objective-C method 'paymentQueue:removedTransactions:' provided by method 'paymentQueue(*:removedTransactions:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'paymentQueue(*:removedTransactions:)' in protocol 'SKPaymentTransactionObserver'

Also, in the video - the dude has no errors showing on his and he is able to run the app.

Does anyone have idea why I am getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

How about the correct method from `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("removed")
}
```

See [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPaymentTransactionObserver/paymentQueue:removedTransactions:).